# Не работает метод Insert() в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, insert

По нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        text1.Text.Insert(3, "-");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C# строковые переменные (тип `String`) являются неизменяемыми (immutable). По этой причине значение, которое хранится в поле свойства `Text` вашего тексбокса, остаётся прежним. Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx), метод `String.Insert(Int32, String)`, возвращает изменённую строку, но не изменяет исходную. Поэтому, Ваш метод должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    text1.Text = text1.Text.Insert(3, "-");
}
```

Этот код выполнит вставку и вернёт изменённое значение, которое затем присвоится свойству `Text` для текстбокса.

Цитата из статьи [Strings, immutability and persistence](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/07/19/strings-immutability-and-persistence/):

> One of the benefits of the immutable data types I’ve talked about here previously is that they are not just immutable, they are also “persistent“. By “persistent”, I mean an immutable data type such that common operations on that type (like adding a new item to a queue, or removing an item from a tree) can re-use most or all of the memory of an existing data structure. Since it is all immutable, you can re-use its parts without worrying about them changing on you.
>
> Strings in this format are immutable, but they are not persistent,
>   thanks to that pesky single-buffer-with-both-a-prefix-and-suffix
>   layout. Concatenation two strings does not re-use the content of
>   either of the original strings; it creates a new string and copies the
>   two strings into the new string. Taking the substring of a string does
>   not re-use the content of the original string. Again, it just makes a
>   new string of the right size and makes a full copy of the data.